# How does an accuracy specified in vol% translates to ppm?

Tags: measurements, units, error-analysis

I need to setup some CO2 concentration measurement. The datasheet of the sensor is:

> Range: 0 to 25 vol%
>
> Accuracy < 0.5 vol% + 3% of measured value

[vol%](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_fraction) is the percentage by volume. So the range is: 0 ppm to 250,000 ppm.
Then what is the right reading for accuracy, including an example for the measurement of 400 ppm of CO2 in standard air, let's call it `uca` for *use case accuracy*?

1. `0.5 vol%` is equal to `5,000 ppm` ==> `uca =  5,000 ppm + 3% of 400 ppm = 5012 ppm`
2. `0.5 vol%` is relative to range ==> `uca = 0.5% of 250,000 ppm + 3% of 400 ppm = 1262 ppm`
3. `0.5 vol%` is relative to the actual concentration ==> `uca = 0.5% of 400 ppm + 3% of 400 ppm = 14 ppm`
4. something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The volume percentage is a ratio of two volumes. Hence, it is a  dimensionless number. The same is true for ppm. Thus, you transform according to
$$1 vol\% = 0.01 = 0.01 \cdot 10^6 ppm = 10^4 ppm$$
as you did. The interpretation is that if you divide the volume in one million parts and select ten thousand of these parts, you selected $1\%$ of all parts. In the following, we will treat vol% as a proper unit, just like $m$ or $kg$.

Suppose we have a scale and the data sheets says:

> Range: 0 to 25 kg
>
> Accuracy < 0.5 kg + 3% of measured value

and we measure the value 4kg. The accuracy of this measurement is $0.5kg + 3\% \cdot 4kg$.
Let's transform this logic to your problem: The accuracy is
$$0.5 vol\% + 3\%\cdot 400ppm 
= 0.5 \cdot 10^4 ppm + 3\%\cdot 400ppm = 5012ppm
$$